# Why can't the template parameter lists of a template and its template member be combined?

Tags: c++, templates

I am reading "C++ Programming Language by Stroustrup" and it is mentioned in that as

> Note that the template parameter lists of a template and its template member cannot be combined.

And the example is given as below.

```
template<class T>
  template<class T2> Ptr<T>::operator Ptr<T2> () { return Ptr<T2>(p); }

template<class T, class T2> // error
  Ptr<T>::operator Ptr<T2> () { return Ptr<T2>(p); }
```

I don't understand why it isn't allowed, can someone explain why it isn't?

Comment: are you looking for language specification? or examples where this could be problematic?

Comment: examples will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because these are two different templates (a templated class and a templated member function of that class), and whoever was drawing up the specification, decided that it was necessary to keep it visible in function definitions.

I think it's entirely logical. If it was done the way you are proposing, a programmer reading your code would probably think that there is a single templated class with two parameters, and he'd be wrong.

Comment: So, the second template is interpreted ONLY as a member function of a class taking two parameters and not as a template member to the class taking one parameter?

Comment: No, it looks like you have a templated class `Ptr<T>` and a templated member function of that class - a conversion operator `operator Ptr<T2> ()`. Each of these two templates takes one parameter.

Comment: So, even though I can able to identify the second one is templated member of a class template, the merging is not allowed because somebody may read it wrong

Comment: Yes, I think that's why that requirement is in the specification. Mind you - that someone might be you, after you yourself forget your code.

Comment: OK, thanks, I can accept this answer now but from my experience with my previous questions, i think i'll wait for some time (a day may be) in case there are going to be other answers. I hope thats OK.

Comment: That's fine, I am not here for the reputation. What would I do with it, pickle it? ))